# Trying to run Specflow tests but error returned - Unit Test Provider already specified

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, specflow

I've been looking at similar questions on different websites in the hope I could find an answer for it but I've not come across something which has worked for me.

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution (.Net Framework) which contains Specflow related tests. I can see all my tests in the Test Explorer but when I try to run any of them, I am returned with the error 'Unit test provider already specified'. My test runner was initially Specflow.SpecRun but I have since removed all references to this and am now using Specflow.MsTest - this is to allow me to associate my test cases to one in Azure DevOps. Only after making this change, I am getting these errors.

I have searched across my solution and there are no longer any references to SpecRun; there are no build errors either. The 'Enable SpecflowSingleFileGenerator' setting is set to False, I do have an app.config file but do not have a specflow.json file - I read that that is only needed for .NET Core projects.

Has anyone else come across the above or have any ideas to resolving it as I am a bit stuck.

Comment: I had the same, restarting visual studio did the trick.  I now have Specflow, Specflow.MsTest, Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, MsTest.TestAdapter, MsTest.TestFramework, Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk, Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost

Comment: you need to clear the Custom Tool on the features too

Comment: I've checked the CustomTool property for all my features and it is blank. I also installed the Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk, Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost as was missing those two. Cleaned the solution, rebuilt - still same error. I also, restarted my computer, cleaned and built but still getting the same error.

Comment: All I can think is there's another runner in the mix, Nunit?

Comment: I've looked at all the NuGet packages I've installed on my project and I cannot see any reference to NUnit at all. I'm going to create a new project in the same solution and install the required packages then copy all my files across and see if this resolves my issue in the interim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem when I moved from nUnit to MsTest. I want to add few more steps to comments mentioned

1. Check your feature.cs files and make sure it has only`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` attributes and not nUnit or specrun
2. Check whether you are using any `local.testsettings` file in visual studio
3. Remove nUnit from tools and extensions if you are not using it.
4. Restart VS, clear temp folder, clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

So this may not be the most ideal solution but I created a new project within the same solution, installed the same nuget packages and copied all the files/folders across to the new project. I removed the previous project, cleaned solution and re-built. Tests appear in the Test Explorer and also run successfully too.